# Wordpress transfer to another domain

Tags: php, wordpress, web-hosting

I had a wordpress site which was on a site with this name: marketingactivo.com.ec 
I copy all the files and database to another domain with this name: http://marketingactivo.info/migrated
I changed the database information in config file to a new server information.
But when I browser it http://marketingactivo.info/migrated , nothing work and for all the links,CSS , images , etc ... the wordpress is still looking on the old domain with .com.ec name. Should I look for more configuration inside wordpress files? I can not not even go to login page becasue it redirect me to the old domain and that domain does not exist anymore!

Comment: WordPress has the nasty habit of using absolute URLs all over the database. I suggest you use the WP Migrate DB plugin, it allows to to switch out URL and local file system paths part while creating a database dump (accessing it via the old domain), that you can then simply upload into your new database.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to the old site, I just have files backup and database backup, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Well then you'll have to do a search&replace of the URLs and file system path in the database content yourself, using a text editor or some other means.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this : https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

It's a script that replace all occurrences of your old domaine, into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ once the site is up at the new domain.

That tool correctly works with serialized data in the database - unlike using SQL queries directly in the database - so your theme options, widgets and menus don't break. Using SQL queries will break serialized data and you will lose theme options, widget placements, etc.

The interconnectit tool has an option to be able to do a "dry run" beforehand so you can see what will be changed in the database.

Once the site files and database have been uploaded to the new domain folder, don't try to login or view the site at the new domain, just upload the tool folder via FTP and use it to change URLs.

You may also have to change hardcoded URLs in style sheets and the theme's `functions.php` file; the interconnectit tool, of course, can't do that.

Answer (score -1):

Please go to your database via phpmyadmin and open table wp_options.

Run a query like

```
       SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home'
```

You need to change these two values to your new url.

Comment: This code won't change links inside post, media link, or any post_meta containing url.

Comment: Don't do this -- this won't work like you think it will, and will likely break many links in your site.

Comment: Actually, what I have written must be done otherwise your newly migrated website will constantly redirect back to the old domain name.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever I migrate Wordpress websites I always run the following `SQL` commands on the database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

The below link is a really good summary of what you should do when migrating to a new domain:

SRC: https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/

Comment: Your SQL query method breaks serialized data in the database; you can read the notes about that farther down the page of the link you posted. Best to use the tool linked in the article: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/